# Background image not loading for relative layout in android

Tags: android, background, android-relativelayout

In my android xml code, I want to draw a background image for a relative layout:

I have a file called `homeBackground.png`. But its not actually showing up when I run on my phone. If I look in the GUI editor for the layout, I can see the background.

Does anyone know what's wrong here?

Thanks.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:background="@drawable/homeBackground"
    tools:context=".ActivityCourses" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**EDIT:**

Now I get this

```
[2013-10-13 02:21:10 - NAME] res\drawable-hdpi\homeBackground.png: Invalid file name: must contain only [a-z0-9_.]
```

Comment: do you get any exceptions?

Comment: no, it compiles and runs without errors on my phone.

Comment: you have image in which dpi folder ?

Comment: I test on Samsung Galaxy SIIX

Comment: I updated the question above with an error message...

Comment: I found the issue, it can't have any capital letters in the name.

Comment: Yes thats it. Change the image name and you are done...

Answer (score 1):

Capital letters not allowed in resources files.

Instead of

```
homeBackground.png
```

rename the file name to:

```
home_background.png
```